# Adding values for function returns within Angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I currently have a calculation which is performed within an ng-repeat row, which does some simple multiplication and returns a total.

Here is the function:

```
$scope.lineTotal = function(line){
    var markup = 1 + (line.markupPct / 100);
    var discount = 1 - (line.discountPct / 100);

    return line.price * discount * markup * line.qty;
}
```

How do i add all these returns at the end, to come up with a subtotal of all?

Comment: There are multiple ways this could be solved, but each possible solution depends on a few other factors (are you using a filter on your `ng-repeat`, for example).  It would be easier to write a workable solution with a bit more information regarding the data that is being provided and the markup that is being used.

Comment: you could have a $scope.totals array and push each total into it

Comment: There are no filters on the ng-repeat no.  @SergioMarron - how would i push these values to a totals array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to calculate the line total on each line and display it would be to run an `angular.forEach` (see [angular.forEach docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)) on the set of lines and add the result to another `$scope.total` variable:

```
angular.forEach($scope.lines, function(value, key) {
  $scope.total += $scope.lineTotal(value);  
});
```

Then simply display total in the template, `{{total}}`

Here's an example on plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Vvn5OuxIMng470yxu9LU?p=preview